# Can't open post in single page

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress

I have problem with my Wordpress blog, 
in mobile I can't open the post in single page because the post in main page doesn't response with any click or touch on phone,
the div class for post on main page is entry-content.

this mobile styling codes

```
    /* =Mobile Styling
----------------------------------------------- */

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .pull-right {
    float: none !important;

  }
  .pull-left {
    float: none !important;
  }



  .site-info, .copyright {
      text-align: right;

  }

  .footer-nav.nav, .copyright {
    float: none;

  }

  .site-content {
    width: 100%;
}

  .flex-caption {
    display: none;
  }
  .navbar > .container .navbar-brand {
    margin: 0;

  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    line-height: 20px;
    padding: 15px 10px;
  }

  #footer-area {
  display: none;
  }

  .entry-content {
    margin-left: 0;
    display: inline;

    }
```

Comment: Is it about styling or coding?

Comment: @FakhruddinUjjainwala The clicks works in desktop mode in addition, I tried to margin-left post in main page and the clicks responses works but when I made fit on mobile screen they doesn't work.

Comment: can I have your HTML please?

Comment: @FakhruddinUjjainwala abood250.com

Comment: Your button is getting hidden behind `<div class="form-group">` check inspect element.

Comment: @FakhruddinUjjainwala So do I have to move <div class="form-group"> more down?

Comment: not the best person to solve rendering related queries. Although you can try out that. Also consider posting the question in CSS section.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting entry-content position:relative and z-index high (like 999) and see what happens. Also try removing display:inline or change do display:block.

Hope it helps